# Format if table value does not match first row

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have test results data in Excel like this:

```
Correct  d  b   c   a   b   c   d
Student1 d  b   c   a   b   c   d
Student2 d  b   c   a   b   c   a
Student3 d  b   c   a   b   d   d
Student4 d  d   c   a   b   c   a
Student5 d  d   c   a   b   c   d
Student6 d  b   c   a   b   b   d
```

I want to highlight the cells that contain incorrect answers.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answer makes little sense to me hence an alternative:

[image: SO17703494 example]

Answer (score 2):

*Step 1:*
Shortcut Key for New Conditional Formatting Rule: Alt-H-L-N
OR
Windows Ribbon Path: Home, Conditional Formatting, New Rule.

*Step 2:*
Got the last selection: Use a formula to choose which cells to format
Use the following Formula:
Conditional Formatting Rule:
=AND(B2<>"",B2<>B$1).

*Step 3:*
Copy the formatting in Cell B2 to all of the other students answers
To copy only the formatting, copy cell B2
Then select all the cells that you want to have this formatting
Then hit Alt-E-S-T (Keys are hit one after the other) for Special Paste
Then hit OK.

Comment: If you highlight the area starting from B2 before creating the conditional formatting formula you won't have to copy the formatting afterwards.

Comment: OK.  So the trick is to use a boolean function even though it doesn't look like you need one.  I could have used =AND(B2<>B$1,TRUE).  Seems like a pointless hack just to get the relative referencing to copy properly.